# CORS issues with CloudFront and S3

Tags: amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront

Some of our users are getting this error in the browser consoles:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://d2ynz9y5qgba7.cloudfront.net/icons/instagram.svg.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'https://www.weld.io'; is therefore not allowed access.
```

These are the current headers:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Age: 21038
Content-Length: 1086
Content-Type: image/svg+xml
Date: Wed, 23 Mar 2016 10:00:12 GMT
Etag: "5cc3b790e15d7736b95880001521630b"
Last-Modified: Wed, 18 Mar 2015 10:20:32 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
Via: 1.1 8cdc69e06e564b9aef153cf0b52204b0.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: 0lD_0czYTm6i5f7RlURkG2dcQx_B252LC2GOu98anzHH1k1eaz2lmg==
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
```

As you can see, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is indeed present.

We are also "whitelisting" `Origin` on CloudFront.

What could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Did you perhaps add, modify, or correct your CORS configuration on S3 *after* the object was already cached in some edge locations?  If I send `Origin: https://www.weld.io` with the request headers, I actually get back `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.weld.io` `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET` `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`.  This is different than your response, which has an `Age:` (how long it's been cached) of several hours, which implies you may have been changing it recently.  My response was a cache miss.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes I added `<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>` to S3 CORS, but that was after users were starting to have these problems. Before that, there was no recent change.